# Symfony2 Ajax form & Edit action

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I am using symfony 2.3 and I am working with Ajax forms. This is my schema, I am using FOSUserBundle and I added an extra table for the user profile. In the showProfile action I get the corresponding UserProfile from the database if its created, and send the form to the view, for now everything is working great.

For process the form request, I created another action that returns a JsonResponse, this action process the UserProfile form request, my code looks like this:

```
public function processProfileAction(Request $request)
    {
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());

        $userProfile = new UserProfile();
        $formFactory = $this->container->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');
        $postform = $formFactory->createForm();
        $postform->setData($userProfile);
        if ($request->isMethod('POST') ) 
        { 
            $postform->bind($request);
            $response = new JsonResponse();
            if ($postform->isValid()) 
            {                
                $userProfile->setUser($user);

                $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
                $em->persist($userProfile);
                $em->flush();

                $response->setData(array("Success" => true, "Message" => "Your data was saved successfully"));
            }
            else {
                $response->setData(array("Success" => false, "Cause" => "Invalid form data"));
            }
            return $response;
        }
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(array("Success" => false, "Cause" => "Method is not POST"));
        return responde;
    }
```

If I want to edit the user profile, the error says:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

This is the form in the view:

```
<form id="user_profile_form" action="{{ path('_process_user_profile') }}" {{ form_enctype(userProfileForm) }} method="POST">
                    {{ form_errors(userProfileForm) }}
                    {{ form_widget(userProfileForm._token) }}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <div class="widget_error">{{ form_errors(userProfileForm.first_name) }}</div>
                            <div class="form-row" style="width:250px;">
                                {{ form_widget(userProfileForm.first_name, {'label': null, 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'placeholder.first_name'|trans}} ) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <div class="widget_error">{{ form_errors(userProfileForm.last_name) }}</div>
                            <div class="form-row" style="width:250px;">
                                {{ form_widget(userProfileForm.last_name, {'label': null, 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'placeholder.last_name'|trans}} ) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">{{ 'buttons.save_changes'|trans }}</button></div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

I understand that the user profile already exist and I am trying to create a new one with the same user_id, how can I fix this? Am I missing something???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own code.  I did't create a new `UserProfile` instance before binding the form.

This is what I do:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();            
$userProfile = $em->getRepository('AloBundle:UserProfile')->findOneBy(array("user" => $user->getId()));
if ((!isset($userProfile))) $userProfile = new UserProfile();
```

I try to retrieve the actual `UserProfile` from the database, and if it doesn't exist, I create a new one.  The code works perfectly.